# Constant value - initialize with class

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class called `ConsoleTheme`, which is a base class for console themes like Dark and Light themes.

```
public abstract class ConsoleTheme
{
    public abstract ConsoleColor BackgroundColor { get; }
}
```

I want to have a constant value in my constants class so any class that can is inherited from the class `ConsoleTheme` can be chosen.

```
public class LightTheme : ConsoleTheme
{
    public override ConsoleColor BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it says that those classes are used like a variable, but they're a type. How can I make that work?

For example:

```
public const ConsoleTheme = LightTheme;
```

Comment: public const ConsoleTheme = LightTheme; -> public const ConsoleTheme `ConsoleTheme` = LightTheme;

Comment: Are you sure this should be `const`? Because then it can NOT be changed at runtime and thats normaly the meaning of themes...

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class ConsoleTheme
{
    public abstract ConsoleColor BackgroundColor { get; }
}

public class LightTheme : ConsoleTheme
{
    public override ConsoleColor BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public ConsoleTheme ct = new LightTheme();
```

I'm not sure why you want to make this a constant or static. Instead you can instantiate the correct IConsoleThemePicker at startup, and pass this instance to whatever class needs it (manually or using dependency injection). This makes it flexible and testable.

```
 public interface IConsoleThemePicker
 {
      ConsoleTheme GetCurrentConsoleTheme();
 }

 public class DefaultConsoleThemePicker : IConsoleThemePicker
 {
      public ConsoleTheme GetCurrentConsoleTheme();
 }
```

Usage:

```
 public class SomeClass
 {
      private readonly IConsoleThemePicker _consoleThemePicker;
      public SomeClass(IConsoleThemePicker consoleThemePicker)
      {
           _consoleThemePicker = consoleThemePicker;
      }
      public void SomeMethod()
      {
           var theme = _consoleThemePicker.GetCurrentConsoleTheme();
           // use theme
      }
 }
```

Comment: I want it to be a constant so I can easily change it. Is there a way that I can make it be static, but still inherit from the class (so I can have "default" varabiesl)

Comment: The whole point of [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) is that you **can't** change it at runtime.

Comment: Don't know what you want to achieve; but you can just use the ct field, and pass it to whatever class needs it; make it a public property etc. No need for const.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what has been already said, you perhaps want to have a simple way of selecting among themes, like you have with colors or brushes (i.e. `Brushes.Red`).

You can do something like this:

```
static class ConsoleThemes
{
    public static readonly ConsoleTheme Light = new LightTheme();
    public static readonly ConsoleTheme Dark = new DarkTheme();   
}
```

So then you can say:

```
var theme = ConsoleThemes.Light;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create an instance of the `LightTheme` class as it is not static.

Answer (score 0):

Class instances can't be assigned to a [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) field. You have to create an instance and assign it to a `static readonly` field.

```
public static readonly ConsoleTheme ConsoleTheme = new LightTheme();
```

Though it sounds like a bad idea to have a read-only theme :)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a class, you need to create an object of that class to be able to use it.

Create objects using the `new` keyword, like so.

```
public const ConsoleTheme theme = new LightTheme();
```